# Jenkins MSBuild failed for .Net Core 2.0

Tags: jenkins

I keep getting the following error when trying to build a .Net Core project:

Unable to locate the .NET Core SDK. Check that it is installed and that the version specified in global.json (if any) matches the installed version.

My project wasn't created with a global.json and from what I understand I don't actually need it.  I verified that my server has the .NET Core SDK installed and my installation of Jenkins is pointing to MS Build.

Answer (score 0):

In our case this issue was caused by existing `MSBuildSDKsPath` environment variable that was pointing to `C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.402\Sdks`. This variable existed as a workaround for Visual Studio Build Tools 2017 prior to `15.9.11`. Newer version fails with the same error when variable exists.